# Sequencing actions with async db programming

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, pg-promise

New to async and struggling. As an example below I wish to init a table then process it's contents by:
a) Remove old data
b) Insert a new record
c) Read the table into an array
d) Display the array

```
'use strict';


// ================================================================================
// Module dependencies
var pgp      = require('pg-promise')();


// ================================================================================
//Configure the database connection
var config = {
  user:               'user', //env var: PGUSER 
  database:           'database', //env var: PGDATABASE 
  password:           'password', //env var: PGPASSWORD
};
var db = pgp(config);


// ================================================================================
// Initialise rhe variables
var customers = [];


// ================================================================================
// Initialise table
db.none("DELETE FROM testing")
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("Deleted old records");
    // success;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

db.none("INSERT INTO testing (firstname, surname) VALUES ('Bob', 'Brown')")
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("Inserted new record");
    // success;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });


// ================================================================================
// Display records
db.any("SELECT * FROM testing")
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("Looping records");
    data.forEach(function(row, index, data) {
      customers.push(row.firstname, row.lastname);
      console.log(row);
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

console.log("The customers are:");
console.log(customers);
```

The output is not as desired but somewhat as expected. Interestingly after "Inserted new records" there is a 30 second wait before the command prompt is retuned.

```
The customers are:
[]
Looping records
anonymous {
  id: 3,
  firstname: 'Bob',
  surname: 'Brown',
  created: 2016-08-03T01:43:34.880Z }
Deleted old records
Inserted new record
```

My question is ultimately with async programming surely there are scenarios where actions need to be performed in sequence such as the example above and in such a scenario how can this be coded in an async environment such as node.js.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a library that supports promises to access the database, you should do each step in the next `.then` method. If you don't perform the steps in the `.then` method, then each statement is executed on the current "tick" until there are no more statements for that "tick". The async methods (called with `db.none(...)` are executing on a future "tick". This is way you see the last 2 `console.log` statements as the first ones to output.

Try changing your code to something like below for a better workflow:

```
'use strict';


// ================================================================================
// Module dependencies
var pgp      = require('pg-promise')();


// ================================================================================
//Configure the database connection
var config = {
  user:               'user', //env var: PGUSER 
  database:           'database', //env var: PGDATABASE 
  password:           'password', //env var: PGPASSWORD
};
var db = pgp(config);


// ================================================================================
// Initialise rhe variables
var customers = [];


// ================================================================================
// Initialise table
db.none("DELETE FROM testing")
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("Deleted old records");
    // success;

    return db.none("INSERT INTO testing (firstname, surname) VALUES ('Bob', 'Brown')");
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("Inserted new record");
    // success;

    // Display records
    return db.any("SELECT * FROM testing");
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("Looping records");
    data.forEach(function(row, index, data) {
      customers.push(row.firstname, row.lastname);
      console.log(row);
    });
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log("The customers are:");
    console.log(customers);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

See how each action/step is in another `.then` method. Also, since the `db.` methods return promises, you can return those inside the `.then` methods and the next `.then` will execute when that statement is finished.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. Can I ask: (a) does "return" before the db statement allow it to be linked to the next ".then" as opposed to being nested which was my initial expectation? (b) why does "db.none" impact the ordering, i didnt get that point sorry. (c) what if I wanted to insert two records instead of one, could you possibly amend your example to show this. Thanks again.

Comment: Thinking this through further. If the ".then" section is what is executed after the async action has completed then is this not what a "callback" does. Or are promises the evolution of callbacks meaning there is no longer a need to use callbacks.

Comment: You also should execute it against the same connection, by using `task` or `tx`. I will publish my detailed answer in a few hours when I get a moment. In the meantime, have a look at [Chaining Queries](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/chaining-queries).

Comment: On qn (c) above I read that I can use batches to action multiple query statements at the one time however this sounds a lot like that a tx does.

Comment: I was responding to the question of how the async workflow is handled in your example. I'm not familiar with the `pg-promise` library so I'm not sure exactly what `.none` does. For promises, the `.then` is like the callback but it gets the results and `.catch` gets the errors. When you return a promise inside the `.then` callback, it chains the promises so the results of the second next are passed to the next `.then`. @vitaly-t will probably provide a better example for specific `pg-promise` use cases.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would depend on whether or not there is a dependency between the queries. If they are dependent, you chain them as you would promises; otherwise you can execute them in parallel as a batch:

```
'use strict';

var promise = require('bluebird');

var pgp = require('pg-promise')({
    promiseLib: promise // use a custom promise library
});

var config = {
    user: 'user', //env var: PGUSER 
    database: 'database', //env var: PGDATABASE 
    password: 'password', //env var: PGPASSWORD
};

var db = pgp(config);

function prepareCustomers(t) {
    return t.batch([
        t.none('DELETE FROM testing'),
        t.none('INSERT INTO testing VALUES($1, $2)', ['Bob', 'Brown']),
        t.any('SELECT * FROM testing')
    ])
        .then(data=>data[2]); // get results from the select query
}

db.tx(prepareCustomers)
    .then(customers=> {
        console.log(customers);
    })
    .catch(error=> {
        console.log(error);
    })
    .finally(pgp.end); // only call pgp.end when exiting the application
```

Also, when you are making changes in a database like this, you would normally use a transaction for this, as shown in the example above.

> Interestingly after "Inserted new records" there is a 30 second wait before the command prompt is retuned.

See [Library de-initialization](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#library-de-initialization)

Comment: Thanks you again. Would I be correct in understanding that the example about should be chained as a batch would return unreliable results as the old needs to be removed before the new is inserted before the new can be returned?

Comment: It appears to be that a batch is like a tx with the only difference being the ability to rollback so I could always use a tx when a batch was required.

Comment: @user1567212 on one hand, the `batch` executes all queries in parallel. However, it executes them against the same IO channel, which turns them into a synchronous sequence. This is how transactions are done. So it is reliable. And you should only use `tx` when changing data, so you need to roll back; otherwise use `task` for executing multiple independent read-only queries.